# Configure Linux PC as router

Tags: networking, routing

Consider the below network configuration.

```
wan ----[WAN router] <----> [eth1 (PC2) eth0]<---->[eth0 (PC1)]
wan ----[WAN router 192.168.169.1] <--> [192.168.169.5 (PC2) 10.1.2.3] <--> [10.1.2.2 (PC1)]
```

I am trying access internet from PC1 through PC2. PC2 is connected to a 3g router. I am using [Olive V-R15 Pocket Rocket](http://www.olivetelecom.in/Olive-V-R15-Pocket-Rocket.html). I have added static routes as below for my objective.

**In PC1:-**

```
#set 10.1.2.3 as default gateway
sudo route add default gw 10.1.2.3 eth0
```

**In PC2:-**

```
#set 192.168.169.1 as default gateway
sudo route add default gw 192.168.169.1 eth1
```

**In WAN router:-**

```
#Add static route to 10.1.2.0/24 via 192.168.169.5
```

[image: WAN router - routing table]

With the above configuration i can able to ping WAN router IP `(192.168.169.1)` from PC1. But when i tried to ping `8.8.8.8`(aka www.google.com), i couldn't. i did a traceroute at PC1 and here is the output.

```
traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.2.3 (10.1.2.3)  27.179 ms  27.117 ms  28.014 ms
 2  192.168.169.1 (192.168.169.1)  28.334 ms  28.655 ms  29.831 ms
 3  220.224.141.145 (220.224.141.145)  129.838 ms  130.853 ms  132.844 ms
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C (tracroute failed)
```

I don't why i can able ping till WAN router but not beyond that. I can do IP masquerading in PC2 for my requirement. But i would like to know what am i doing wrong with this method. Could someone clarify me? Thank you.

Comment: your routing looks OK to me.. Maybe you are not NATting the connection?

Comment: I agree with @Silent-Bob. It's likely the 10.1.2.0/24 network is not being NATted on the WAN router before sending it out to the 'net. This traffic will be dropped if not by your ISP, somewhere up the chain. Even if it did make it to Google, there would be no route back. Either NAT to 192.168.169.x on PC2, or make WAN router NAT the 10.1.2.0/24 block to the WAN IP.

Comment: I know how to NAT on PC2. But is it possible to add NAT on commercial routers for user defined subnet?